# How to increase the size of an 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, char, 2d

I would like to have a display like this:

[image: expandable array]

**goal**: each time a `char` is added, the matrix will automatically create an empty line after inserting a `char` type.

I don't know

1. if using a matrix is a good idea to achieve what I want
2. where to start, as I have not written any code yet

Thank you for helping me out, I am a beginner in java!

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a free code writing service where we do all of your homework. Do some research and start writing some code and we can help you from there. A hint, if you are willing to learn then collection types like [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) are much more flexible than basic arrays

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Amongst the other issues with this question, you might like to check the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)  and avoid language that assumes that everyone on StackOverflow is a man.

Answer (score 2):

There exist `List` classes in java, which have an **expandable length**.

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

will create (like `char[] list = new char[...];` a list of chars, but of **expandable length**.

Usage

To insert a char `item` at index `index` (like `list[index] = item;`)

```
list.add(index, item);
```

To place a char `item` at the end of the `list`

```
list.add(item);
```

To access an item of `list` at an index `index`

```
list.get(index);
```

And

If you need something similar to **2D arrays** (`char[][] list = new char[...][...]`), use

```
List<List<Character>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and if you add a row to the `list`

```
list.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Usage

To insert a char `item` at row `row` and column `col`

```
list.get(row).add(col, item);
```

To place a char `item` at the end of `row` of the `list`

```
list.get(row).add(item);
```

To access an item of `list` at row `row` and column `col`

```
list.get(row).get(col);
```

Comment: an example of arraylists: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

Comment: That's not a matrix.

Comment: Thx for your explanations. But, I didn't get the idea of 2D arrays: List<List<Character>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @TimDev: 1. ArrayList implements List  2. the type (Character or List<Character>) is transfered, if it is not specified further  **→ List<...> list = new ArrayList<>();**  (could be also written as: ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayIist<Character>>();)

Answer (score 1):

You can create static arrays in Java, dynamic arrays are not possible in java, but you can use other data structures (`Collection`s) in Java to achieve this

Here I use the concept of a jagged array to solve your problem. We can create a 2-D array, but with variable number of columns in each row. This will work only if you have a known number of rows.

```
char a[][] = new char[][5];
a[0] = new char[1];
a[1] = new char[6];
a[2] = new char[6];
a[3] = new char[6];
a[4] = new char[6];
```

You can use this concept with `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList[][] arraylist = new ArrayList[10][];
```

If you are working with pattern then you should use for-loops to print / acheive the pattern.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character> > x 
        = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character> >();

x.add(new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('4')));
x.add(new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('3','x',' ',' ',' ','e')));
x.add(new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('2','x',' ','d','d','e')));
x.add(new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('1','x','a','d','d','e')));
        x.add(new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(' ','1','2','3','4','5')));

System.out.println(x);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your help, I started to understand the basics. But the problem is that I want a 2d array in which I can add a row and an element in any position, it's like Tetris if every time I want to add an element it will automatically add a row if there is now row available or add the element at the position decided. So, here what i did but not sure it will work: private ArrayList<char []> grille = new ArrayList<char []>();